# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf Resource folder Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to set resource folder in my Spring Boot project. But not able to make it. Please help. I am trying to integrate thymeleaf.

[image: Project Structure]

I am able to get index.html
But I am not able to include resource /css/mobile-angular-ui-desktop.min.css file in index.html.
It give me 404 Page Not found error.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Provision Admin</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/mobile-angular-ui-base.min.css}"
    href="../static/css/mobile-angular-ui-base.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/css/mobile-angular-ui-desktop.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var appContext = '/profilebatch';

</script>


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I setting following security.

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends
            WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private SecurityProperties security;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**")
                    .permitAll().antMatchers("**/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/secure/**").fullyAuthenticated().and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .permitAll().and().logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user")
                    .roles("USER").and().withUser("admin").password("admin")
                    .roles("ADMIN");
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does the `href` in the actual rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally things are working fine.
I removed @EnableWebMvc in my configuartion.

Answer (score -1):

you don't have th:href for desktop, if you can access base so this is your problem:

```
th:href="@{/css/mobile-angular-ui-desktop.min.css}"
```

Comment: please share more details, is there any error in logs?

Comment: please confirm that the base one is working perfect and your only problem with desktop one, use firebug or developer tools to be sure.
if base one is working desktop have to work too.

Comment: ok now it is logic, I think you are using @enablewebmvc and extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter so you will need to Override addResourceHandlers

Answer (score -1):

Static resources default place at /public instead of /src/main/resources/static

Comment: I tried that but still it is issue. I have set ContentNegotiation deafult as APPLICATION_JSON for my Rest service. I have both together Rest & Web Thymeleaf. Any Idea of excluding the folder for ContentNegotiation

Comment: Spring Boot will also serve out of `/static`.

Comment: Can you please explain how?